# How do I cross-compile the kernel on a Ubuntu host?

Tags: cross-compilation, ubuntu

I would like to understand more about how the kernel works. Part of this is to compile it myself. How do I cross-compile the Kernel on a Ubuntu host?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Preparation

First, we need to install the required prerequisites. I assume you have `sudo` access.

```
sudo apt-get install git ncurses-dev make gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

- `git` is the version control system used by the Linux kernel team.
- `ncurses` is a library for build console menus. It is necessary for `menuconfig`.
- `make` runs the compilation for us.
- `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` is the cross-compiler.

Next, we need to retrieve the source, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux raspberrypi-linux
cd raspberrypi-linux
```

This will clone the source code to a directory called `raspberrypi-linux` and change to it.

## Compilation

We first need to move the config file by running

```
cp arch/arm/configs/bcmrpi_cutdown_defconfig .config
```

Then configure the kernel build

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- oldconfig
```

*Optional:* Customise the build using menuconfig

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- menuconfig
```

Then run the compilation

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- -k
```

References

- http://elinux.org/RPi_Kernel_Compilation
- https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux
- http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
- http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-kernel-compile/

Comment: Thank you very much for providing an alternative to using **crosstool-ng**.

Comment: In my case CROSS_COMPILE is just a prefix, so the follow should be enough (without gcc at the end):

```make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi- -k```

Answer (score 4):

I think Alex is right but the gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi is compiled for arm cpus without hardware floating point unit. You can find a cross-compiler with armhf support on: https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools
and a good tutorial to start with here: http://hertaville.com/2012/09/28/development-environment-raspberry-pi-cross-compiler/

Answer (score 1):

**Official documentation**

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md ([GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/3698bc9642fba495bb2798c4b164f2786076efdf/linux/kernel/building.md))

I would recommend that you just follow the steps there, or send a pull request if something becomes outdated or is not clear enough: those instructions are the most likely ones to be correct and up to date since they are part of the official documentation of the project.