# Raspberry Pi Cross-Compilation Failure (arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc)

Tags: software-development, kernel, cross-compilation

I am cross compiling a Linux kernel for my Raspberry Pi from an AMD64 Ubuntu 13.04 system. I found this page to be of help ([How do I cross-compile the kernel on a Ubuntu host?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/192/how-do-i-cross-compile-the-kernel-on-a-ubuntu-host)), but I still get errors about a compiler that does not seem to exist for Ubuntu. Below is my output.

```
collier@Nacho-Laptop:/media/collier/AI/Raspberry/kernel/linux-3.10.4$ make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -k
make: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc: Command not found
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
make[1]: `include/generated/mach-types.h' is up to date.
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc: not found
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 127
make[1]: Target `__build' not remade because of errors.
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/checks.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/data.o
  SHIPPED scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-lexer.lex.o
  SHIPPED scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc-parser.tab.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/dtc.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/flattree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/fstree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/livetree.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/srcpos.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/treesource.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/dtc/util.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/dtc/dtc
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/genksyms.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/keywords.hash.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/lex.lex.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/parse.tab.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/genksyms/genksyms
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/empty.o] Error 127
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/mk_elfconfig
  CC      scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc: not found
make[2]: *** [scripts/mod/devicetable-offsets.s] Error 127
make[2]: Target `__build' not remade because of errors.
make[1]: *** [scripts/mod] Error 2
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/genheaders/genheaders
  HOSTCC  scripts/selinux/mdp/mdp
  HOSTCC  scripts/kallsyms
  HOSTCC  scripts/pnmtologo
  HOSTCC  scripts/conmakehash
  HOSTCC  scripts/bin2c
  HOSTCC  scripts/recordmcount
  HOSTCC  scripts/sortextable
  HOSTCC  scripts/asn1_compiler
make[1]: Target `__build' not remade because of errors.
make: *** [scripts] Error 2
/media/collier/AI/Raspberry/kernel/linux-3.10.4/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc: No such file or directory
/media/collier/AI/Raspberry/kernel/linux-3.10.4/scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc: No such file or directory
make: Target `_all' not remade because of errors.
```

I install every GCC ARM compiler available for Ubuntu (that I saw). The compilation seems to require arm-linux-gnueabi-gccgcc, but I have not found such a compiler. The StackExchange page mentioned above and many pages on the Internet suggest to do what I have done. Did I miss something? How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should try again, replacing:

```
CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

with

```
CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

in your command line.