# How can I determine the current firmware version number?

Tags: firmware

Is there a way to find the current firmware version number?  Either the running version or the version currently installed in `/boot`?

`uname -a` shows only the kernel version, not the GPU "binary blob."

> Related: [How do I update software and firmware?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/164/86)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can check the GPU's firmware version by entering the following on the command line:

```
sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
```

Comment: The real question is why have they put it in such an obscure location?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, It is because of the architurcture of the linux operating system. The /opt folder contains the optional packages, That is why the vcgencmd package must be installed there

Comment: But the firmware version doesn't seem to track with the [release notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt). [Why is that?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100625/how-to-verify-id-of-installed-firmware)

Comment: @seamus no idea you may need to ask the foundation, how does it not track?

Comment: According to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100625/how-to-verify-id-of-installed-firmware) - also confirmed it myself just prior to the comment.

Answer (score 7):

[Steve's answer is correct](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/323/83790), but here are some more details that may be of interest.

The firmware version seems to be identified by two pieces of information:

- A release/commit date
- A 160-bit hash value (AFAIK, the algorithm used to compute the hash is unpublished)

There are two sources for this information:

- from the command line: `sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version`
- from the RPi website: the [**release notes**](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt)

However, as at least [one eagle-eyed contributor here has noted](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100625/how-to-verify-id-of-installed-firmware), the 160-bit hash values from the `vcgencmd version` command and the **release notes** do not match. The reason these hash values do not match for any given release date is that the hash values are computed on different file sets [REFERENCE](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1407#issuecomment-641123966):

[The Organization](https://www.raspberrypi.org/) (and possibly their suppliers/subcontractors) maintain two repositories for the Raspberry Pi firmware. One of the repositories houses the *source code* for the RPi firmware, the other repository houses the compiled/binary version of the firmware. The firmware source code repo is unpublished (i.e. it is *'closed-source'*); the [compiled/binary firmware is housed in this GitHub repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware).

And finally to the point of this answer:

- If you want to know what version of the firmware is on **your** RPi, use `sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version`; i.e. Steve's answer.
- If you want to know the **latest** version of the firmware, check the [**release notes**](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt)

NOTE new link for [**Raspberry Pi OS release notes**](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/release_notes.txt)

- However, know that the the 160-bit hash values in these two sources **will never match**. The only valid comparison between these sources is the dates.

Answer (score 1):

A simple script to print HOSTNAME, date, Firmware date

```
MilliwaysPi4    2020-12-12  Nov 30 2020 22:12:08
```

```
#! /bin/sh
if [ -e /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd ]; then
    VERS=$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version  | grep ":")
fi
echo -e `hostname`'\t'`date -I`'\t'$VERS
```