# How to verify id of installed firmware?

Tags: update, pi-4, raspbian-buster

The [release notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt) for example to date **2019-07-10** shows

```
* Linux kernel 4.19.57
* Raspberry Pi firmware cb3a32adf39f45a49be454e30c7464920ad7c605
```

After an update I can verify the current kernel version with `uname -r`. At [How can I determine the current firmware version number?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/323/79866) I have found how to get the current firmware version:

```
rpi ~$ sudo /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd version
Jul  9 2019 14:37:58
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
version d2b1b7fb01475cb3914b2086299e32d724e832f1 (clean) (release) (start)
```

But as you can see it does not match the release note.

How can I verify the Raspberry Pi firmware version from the release notes?

Comment: @PeterGreen Do you know how to verify the Raspberry Pi firmware version noted in the release notes?

Comment: Have you tried asking this is the [raspberrypi.org forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/)? @Dougie may have some clues?

Comment: and I wonder if they refer to the same firmware package? The **vc** in `vcgencmd` refers to the VideoCore component of Raspberry Pi, but are there other components with firmware? That seems likely (to me), and the [Wikipedia article on the VideoCore technology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VideoCore) is an interesting read for RPi watchers. You can follow [this Q on github](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1407) if interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* I have an answer to this - actually one of the maintainers of the [GitHub repo for Raspberry Pi firmware](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware) has answered your question. The [Q&A is #1407 under the GitHub Issues tab](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1407#issuecomment-641123966).

The answer is not as detailed as I would have liked, but to my reading, it seems there is one repo to house the compiled/binary firmware for Raspberry Pi, and another repo to house the source code. The compiled/binary Raspberry Pi firmware is housed on the GitHub repo linked above. The repo containing the source code for the Raspberry Pi firmware is "unpublished/closed-source". [The Wiki page for the Raspberry Pi (compiled) firmware repo](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/wiki) tells the same story.

And so the answer seems to be this:

- The 160-bit hash reported by `vcgencmd` is the hash of the firmware's source code - source code that is housed in an unpublished/closed-source repo.
- The 160-bit hash in the [**release notes**](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt) is the hash of the [compiled/binary firmware repo hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware).
- Consequently, the **release/commit date** is all you have to rely upon. The dates are at least *close* - I assume there may be a time lag between committing the source files, and committing the binaries since they occur on different repos.

Finally, there's a [related Q&A here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113319/83790)... this question has been around for a while.