# Performance of the Rasperris

Tags: power, usb-power, power-management

The Raspberry pi 4 has a power supply that can deliver a maximum of 15.5 watts.  How much power exactly does the Raspberry use without overclocking at maximum power so that I can connect the appropriate peripherals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With HDMI and LAN, our Raspberry Pi 4 (4 GB version) consumes 3 watts when idling.  We reached a maximum of 11 watts under deliberately generated full load.

Answer (score 2):

The Pi 4 typically uses 600mA. The Pi consortium suggests a 3A and says that maximum current drawn from USB is 1.2A. There are some safety margins that I suggest to respect, but it means that you should recon with 1.8A.

15.5W is very close to these recommendations. So you should respect the maximum of 1.2A.

Comment: Thank you. So can I say that the Rasberry Pi 4 draws 6 Watt at full load? `1,2A * 5V`

Comment: No. You should recon with 1.8A for the Pi. That means 9W. For your peripherals, you must respect the 1.2A. Note that I say peripherals, not USB devices. Using LAN and HDMI may also increase power consumption (see f.e. your own measurements)

Answer (score 2):

> How much power exactly does the Raspberry use...?

There is not an **exact** answer to that question.

Why? It's due to the RPi's thermal management system. If you're interested in some details, you may wish to read [this closely-related Q&A](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114239/pi-4-maximum-power-consumption).

***In other words:*** Your RPi will consume **more power** in a cooler ambient temperature with better airflow than it will in a higher temperature ambient with lower airflow.

In a "typical" environment with low-ish GPU loading, my experience is similar to the 3 Watt power consumption figure in [Ljm Dullaart's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/124489/83790). And FWIW, I have *yet to find* a power supply that will prevent all "Low Voltage Alarms" - even on the `Lite` (headless) distribution.