# RPI 3 /boot full

Tags: boot

I've installed Volumio v2.8.61 on a new mSD card. After making all setting, I checked the /boot folder - it's almost full (95%)! Therefore it's not possible to maka an upgrade. What's wrong?

The outputs below.

Many thanks!

Thomas

```
volumio@volumio:/boot$ df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p2                 2.2G  811M  1.3G  39% /imgpart
/dev/loop0                     347M  347M     0 100% /static
overlay                         13G  383M   12G   4% /
devtmpfs                       471M     0  471M   0% /dev
tmpfs                          485M  1.6M  484M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                          485M  4.7M  481M   1% /run
tmpfs                          5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                          485M     0  485M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                          485M   28K  485M   1% /tmp
tmpfs                          485M     0  485M   0% /var/spool/cups
tmpfs                           20M  208K   20M   2% /var/log
tmpfs                          485M     0  485M   0% /var/spool/cups/tmp
/dev/mmcblk0p1                  61M   57M  3.4M  95% /boot
STORAGE:/tank/Music/POP        6.7T  4.3T  2.5T  64% /mnt/NAS/1-POP
STORAGE:/tank/Music/CLASSICAL  6.7T  4.3T  2.5T  64% /mnt/NAS/3-CLASSICAL
STORAGE:/tank/Music/JAZZ       6.7T  4.3T  2.5T  64% /mnt/NAS/2-JAZZ
tmpfs                           97M     0   97M   0% /run/user/1000

> volumio@volumio:/boot$ ls -la total 57563 drwxrwxrwx 4 root root    
> 3072 Jan  1  1970 . drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 ..
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root       41 Dec 22 14:46 .firmware_revision
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root       41 Dec 22 14:46 .firmware_revision_kernel drwxrwxrwx 2 root root      512 Jan  6 10:13 System Volume Information
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    24246 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    23983 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    23764 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    24424 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2708-rpi-zero-w.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    23688 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2708-rpi-zero.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    25310 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    25459 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2710-rpi-2-b.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    27119 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    26500 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    25314 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    41108 Dec 22 14:46 bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    52360 Dec 22 14:46 bootcode.bin
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root      399 Dec 22 14:47 cmdline.txt
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root      169 Dec 22 14:47 config.txt
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     7272 Dec 22 14:46 fixup.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     5398 Dec 22 14:46 fixup4.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     3151 Dec 22 14:46 fixup4cd.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     8417 Dec 22 14:46 fixup4db.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     8413 Dec 22 14:46 fixup4x.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root     3151 Dec 22 14:46 fixup_cd.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    10261 Dec 22 14:46 fixup_db.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root    10263 Dec 22 14:46 fixup_x.dat
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  5158072 Dec 22 14:46 kernel.img
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  5466824 Dec 22 14:46 kernel7.img
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  5801056 Dec 22 14:46 kernel7l.img drwxrwxrwx 2 root root    16384 Aug  5 17:46 overlays
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  2976416 Dec 22 14:46 start.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  2252288 Dec 22 14:46 start4.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   799836 Dec 22 14:46 start4cd.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  3743076 Dec 22 14:46 start4db.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  3011076 Dec 22 14:46 start4x.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   799836 Dec 22 14:46 start_cd.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  4814916 Dec 22 14:46 start_db.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  3734692 Dec 22 14:46 start_x.elf
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root       90 Dec 22 13:40 userconfig.txt
> -rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 19946350 Dec 22 14:53 volumio.initrd
```

Comment: Whatever Volumio may be, or what it claims to do is unclear, but it is obviously not a standard Raspberry Pi OS so I suggest you ask whoever you got it from.

Comment: From the offical Volumio site (volumio.org) v2.861

Comment: standard /dev/mmcblkp01 size is over 250MB and has been for many years (was smaller at one time) ... whatever volumio is, *it's doing it wrong™* - or perhaps it's deliberate so you can't upgrade

Comment: As I wrote before, it‘s from the official site! What could I do? Take an other download? From which site?

Comment: What is Volumino? A program, running on the *Raspberry Pi OS*? Or a complete image providing the operating system?

Comment: See [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118872/92446) for a guide regarding a way to increase `/boot` without data loss.