# Can I be sure the EEPROM configuration is the latest version?

Tags: usb, boot, hard-drive, pi4-eeprom

I just came across [Pi Dramble cluster](https://www.google.com/search?q=pi%20dramble%20cluster&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBzISZg7jyAhVi8HMBHZx6CUsQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1848&bih=981#imgrc=3mbsHCRA-jbtDM) (I'm also aware it runs Drupal) and [usb boot](https://www.google.com/search?q=rpi%20usb%20boot&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRy6u1g7jyAhWO8XMBHUdpDXcQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1848&bih=981#imgrc=_uRLLFFMQfSkcM) (which gives better performance) and I'll need the latest eeprom configuration to do this.

By the usage of "LATEST", can I conclude the RPis I ordered this morning have the latest configuration?

Comment: If you don't get an answer or don't want to wait for one, the information you are looking for is probably in one of the other questions tagged `pi4-eeprom`: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pi4-eeprom

Comment: ok, so it's better i check each pi @goldilocks .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit *complicated*, so please bear with me:

While ***"LATEST"*** (`latest` actually) now ***is*** a branch of the EEPROM firmware, it ***may not be*** in the sense that you mean. I'll explain that in some detail below, but in the meantime know that the only *definitive* method for specifying an EEPROM firmware release is by its **date**; for example: `Apr 29 2021 17:11:25`. I'll explain this further in the sequel.

Wrt your question:

> "can i conclude the rpis i ordered this morning have the latest configuration?"

The definitive answer to this question: ***"No - you should not conclude this."*** Imagine a factory putting out over 100,000 units a month, all going into a "retail distribution" system where the "new" units are mixed with "old" units and sold by a variety of vendors; each vendor free to sell from their mixed vintage inventory with no rules or oversight from [The RPi Organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Foundation) to govern how this is to be done. ***Fortunately the EEPROM firmware can be updated and managed by the owner/user.***

#### What is the "LATEST" firmware?

First, understand that the term "LATEST" is fraught with ambiguity because the EEPROM firmware is released and maintained under three (3) separate ***branches***:

- `default` - a.k.a. `critical`; roughly corresponds to what you may know as a "stable" release; i.e. one with the lowest risk of "bugs"
- `latest` - a.k.a. `stable`; roughly corresponds to what you may know as a "beta" release; i.e. one not fully tested, but enough to reduce the risk of "bugs"
- `beta` - contains relatively new and lightly-tested features.

And so, each *branch* has its own "LATEST" version (yes, including the `latest` branch!). The branches are on full display in `/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader`:

```bsh
$ ls -l /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader 
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 11 23:27 beta
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 11 23:27 critical
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     8 Jan 14  2021 default -> critical
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     6 Jan 14  2021 latest -> stable
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 27748 Jul  7 08:25 release-notes.md
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jul 11 23:27 stable
```

And if you care to look in the `stable` folder (for example), you may find numerous versions, each filename structured as `pieeprom-YYYY-MM-DD.bin`, where `YYYY-MM-DD` correspond to that version's release date. Furthermore, you can determine the firmware version *currently in use on your system* from the *command line* as follows:

```
$ vcgencmd bootloader_version
```

Which, for my system, yields the following output:

> Apr 29 2021 17:11:25
> version c2f8c388c4ee37ad709ace403467d163e8dd91ce (release)
> timestamp 1619712685
> update-time 1629146551
> capabilities 0x0000001f

And ICYI:

> What is the `version` number here? Answers [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100625/how-to-verify-id-of-installed-firmware), and [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/322/how-can-i-determine-the-current-firmware-version-number/113319#113319).

#### A detailed answer for obtaining the required bootloader firmware:

All of that said, and as a more *practical* answer to your question, once you receive the RPi you ordered, here's how you can get and maintain the "LATEST" firmware - or the firmware you need or want on your system:

- **If you know you want to *"follow"* a particular branch** of the firmware, you may declare that in: `/etc/default/rpi-eeprom-update` by changing the `FIRMWARE_RELEASE_STATUS` variable from its *default* value `FIRMWARE_RELEASE_STATUS="default"` to reflect the branch you wish to follow; e.g. `FIRMWARE_RELEASE_STATUS="latest"`.
  Done in this way, your EEPROM firmware will be updated with your usual update procedure (`sudo apt update`, followed by `sudo apt upgrade`), and it will be *applied* when you `reboot`.
- **If you want to install a particular version of the EEPROM firmware**, this will work:

  ```
  $ sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -f pieeprom.bin
  ```

  Where the generic filename `pieeprom.bin` is replaced by a specific filename. For example, if I want to load and use a file named `pieeprom-2021-07-06.bin` from the `beta` branch, and my `pwd` is `/home/pi`:

  ```
  $ sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -f  /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/beta/pieeprom-2021-07-06.bin
  ```
- **If you want to opt out of future upgrades**, there are two approaches available:

  1. The `systemd` service `rpi-eeprom-update` runs at startup and applies an update if a newer image is available *in the branch you are following*. It may be *suspended* as follows:

     ```
     $ sudo systemctl mask rpi-eeprom-update
     ```
  2. The `FREEZE_VERSION` configuration variable may be declared by editing the EEPROM configuration. This *may be* a better choice than suspending the `rpi-eeprom-update` service in `systemd` in some situations. This is done as follows:

     ```
     $ sudo -E rpi-eeprom-config --edit
     ```

     Once the configuration is opened in the editor, simply add the `FREEZE_VERSION` parameter on a new line.

#### A recap of the detailed answer:

To recap briefly:

- You will need to learn what exactly is meant by `latest eeprom configuration` in the documentation for the software you plan on installing; i.e. is it the "LATEST" in `default`, `latest` or `beta` branch?
- Determine what version of the bootloader your system is currently using via `vcgencmd bootloader_version` as shown above.
- If the desired version is different than the current *in-use* version, you may update to the desired version via `sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -f pieeprom.bin` as shown above.
- Finally, make a decision whether to *track* a particular branch, and apply automatic upgrades, **OR** retain the same bootloader using the `FREEZE_VERSION` configuration variable, or the alternative `systemctl mask` opion as shown above.

---

There is, or at least used to be, ["official documentation" covering much of  this EEPROM configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html), but a [recent overhaul](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2291/the-foundation-has-just-scrambled-their-documentation) of the documentation has either eliminated it, left it in an unknown (to me) location.