# Is it safe to update EEPROM to latest using rpi-eeprom-update?

Tags: bootloader

Ran following and bootloader version is now `000138c0`.

```
$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update -a
```

Asking because `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade -y` does not appear to upgrade bootloader.

I am worried I upgraded to unstable bootloader… can one downgrade bootloader (wasn’t able to find docs on the topic)?

I tried restoring bootloader to factory default (using [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/)) and bootloader version is still `000138c0`.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation?](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-4-boot-eeprom)  If not, please do so, and then consider editing your question.

Comment: Also, [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130741/83790) may be a bit out-of-date, but at least part of it remains valid. FWIW, this EEPROM update has always been a bit obtuse, and it seems to be getting more so as time goes on. But rest assured, there is a way through the thicket.

Comment: Thanks for helping out @Seamus. Would you happen to know how one can downgrade bootloader? I tried resetting bootloader to factory defaults using `sudo raspi-config` but `sudo rpi-eeprom-update` shows both current and latest as `000138c0`.

Comment: @Milliways I get it… what you really meant is “Perhaps you should edit your question to reflect new question in comments (if need be).”. Btw, I stand by my original question and @Seamus pointed me in the right direction. That said, I still don’t feel comfortable having ran `sudo rpi-eeprom-update -a`. Not sure which version of bootloader is safe and how one can downgrade if one upgraded by mistake.

Comment: It is possible to "downgrade" (provided you have an old version) but pointless. There is NOTHING you can't do with current version that you could with older versions (although the default powerdown action changed from initial versions). Newer versions just added more options BUT you need to explicitly enable them. My current eeprom settings are unchanged from initial release (except for power down) which is easily restored.

Comment: First: It's been a while since I had to dig into this pile, but AFAIK, `000138c0` is not actually a version number. Instead, the "version number" is obtained as follows: `vcgencmd bootloader_version`. I rely on [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113317/83790) & the [docs](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#raspberry-pi-4-boot-eeprom) for that opinion. Second: The answer to your question was in the link that I put in my first comment; please read it thoroughly. CONTINUED ==>

Comment: But yes, I think it's possible to "roll back" your EEPROM contents to an earlier version using the `-f` option (ref `man rpi-eeprom-update`) - as was described in the [answer which was linked in my first comment](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130741/83790).  And after walking through what passes for documentation now, I'll try to post an answer now that attempts to address what I ***think*** your concerns are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### QUESTION: Is it safe to update EEPROM to latest using rpi-eeprom-update?

If you use the term "safe" to mean that you won't **brick** your RPi 4, then I would answer your question with a confident "Yes - it is safe." But as always, caveats will apply. Is it "safe" to operate a car on the motorway?... Well, yes, if you fasten your seatbelt, obey the traffic laws, etc. I digress to make the obvious point that "safe" is a relative term - not an absolute one.

You have noted that `apt` does not upgrade the bootloader, but this is only *partially* true. There **is** a default process in place that will perform an [Automatic Update of the EEPROM firmware](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#automaticupdates):

> The `rpi-eeprom-update` systemd service runs at startup and applies an update if a new image is available, automatically migrating the current bootloader configuration.

IOW, `apt` does download the latest firmware, but a `reboot` is required to apply it.

You've said, *"... the bootloader version is now 000138c0."* Again, that is partially true. You're referring to a firmware update file named `vl805-000138c0.bin` that is in the `latest` firmware update stream (the other streams are `beta` and `critical`). However, this update is applied to a different area of the EEPROM than the *bootloader* updates. The VL805 is the Pi 4's USB controller, and its firmware is stored in EEPROM separately from the bootloader firmware (see **Note 1** below).

Firmware revisions are normally identified with a date stamp in the filename; e.g. `pieeprom-2023-01-11.bin`, but as noted above the `vl805` upgrades are *handled a bit differently*. [FWIW, firmware revisions/checksums are confusingly identified in one of 3 different ways](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/113317/83790), but suffice it to say for now that `000138c0` is not one that has ever been used previously!

**You have not upgraded to an unstable bootloader**. The file `vl805-000138c0.bin` has been applied to the USB controller's portion of EEPROM, but the file `pieeprom-2023-01-11.bin` should also have been applied to the bootloader's location in EEPROM. Both files are in the `latest` stream which means that they have been through some testing and verification prior to their release. I *suspect* that the reason `rpi-eeprom-update` reports `000138c0` is the authors simply decided not to put the additional effort into making the output less confusing to users.

Your result for "restoring bootloader to factory default" is likely due to the the "source" of your factory default; IOW, the RPi imager is drawing from the same sources as `apt`, and so *the current factory default **is*** `vl805-000138c0.bin`.

In conclusion, I don't think you have anything to worry about. This business with the USB controller's firmware updates has perhaps not been handled by the RPi organization in the most transparent fashion, but it does appear they've handled it. If you're still concerned, or you want to experiment, please refer to [this other answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/140867/83790). There is also an [older, *related* answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/130741/83790) on EEPROM updates and configuration that may have additional details of interest.

---

###### Note 1:

You didn't mention this in your question, but you can check the installed version of both the bootloader and the vl805 firmware using the `rpi-eeprom-update` script with **no options**. And avoid a confusing error: **run it with root privileges**: `sudo rpi-eeprom-update`. You should see something like this:

```bash
$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update
BOOTLOADER: up to date
   CURRENT: Wed 11 Jan 17:40:52 UTC 2023 (1673458852)
    LATEST: Wed 11 Jan 17:40:52 UTC 2023 (1673458852)
   RELEASE: stable (/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/stable)
            Use raspi-config to change the release.

  VL805_FW: Dedicated VL805 EEPROM
     VL805: up to date
   CURRENT: 000138c0
    LATEST: 000138c0
```

###### Note 2:

The VL805, its firmware and its upgrade process is poorly documented in the official documentation. AIUI, the RPi organization does not have any visibility of the VL805 firmware; it is [proprietary to Via Labs](https://www.viagallery.com/via-labs-vl805/). This raises questions about visibility and quality control, but since ***all*** the RPi firmware is proprietary, this doesn't seem to change much from the user perspective. And looking forward, the Rev 4 RPi 4 boards are said to have disposed of the VL805.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me navigate these changes… outstanding in-dept answers. 

Answer (score 2):

***By default*** EEPROM updates are applied automatically by the system. In brief summary, that upgrade process works as follows:

1. `apt` downloads new *firmware* for the EEPROM when it is available
2. The downloaded firmware is packaged as `*.bin` files, and they are saved to one of three (3) directories under `/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader`
3. Once the new firmware is downloaded, it is written to the EEPROM during the next `reboot`.

You can verify the firmware version currently installed for both the *bootloader* and the *vl805* USB firmware using the `rpi-eeprom-update` script as follows:

```bash
$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update
BOOTLOADER: up to date
CURRENT: Wed 11 Jan 17:40:52 UTC 2023 (1673458852)
 LATEST: Wed 11 Jan 17:40:52 UTC 2023 (1673458852)
RELEASE: stable (/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/stable)
         Use raspi-config to change the release.

VL805_FW: Dedicated VL805 EEPROM
  VL805: up to date
CURRENT: 000138c0
 LATEST: 000138c0
```

Alternatively, the following command will give you the installed firmware status (as above) ***and*** the status of the `systemd` service that automatically updates the firmware:

```bash
$ systemctl status rpi-eeprom-update
```

Many users will not need to read any further; the default configuration will maintain your EEPROM firmware at the version considered to be safest and most reliable. If you're interested in **alternatives** to this default, read on.

##### There are other relevant *details*:

###### 1. Firmware Release Streams

There are 3 *firmware release streams* that reflect 3 different *maturity levels* of the firmware. They are segregated into 3 sub-directories under `/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/` as follows:

| old name | new name | "maturity" |
| --- | --- | --- |
| beta | beta | Least mature |
| stable | latest | Medium maturity |
| critical | default | Most mature |

Notice that soft links have been added to `/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/` that provide *redirection* for the new names to the old names; this should help minimize the confusion created by re-naming the release streams.

###### 2. Choosing your default release stream:

For many people, the default, automatic firmware update process works best. If you ***do nothing to change it***, this process will cause `apt` to download (but not apply) *all* firmware updates as they become available. The latest version from the **critical/default** channel will then be *applied* during the next `reboot`.

But you may decide that you want to keep your firmware a bit *more current* than the **critical/default** stream. If you decide that you wish to follow the **stable/latest** stream, you can change that as follows:

Open the file at `/etc/default/rpi-eeprom-update` in your editor, and replace (or add) the following line:

```
FIRMWARE_RELEASE_STATUS="latest"
```

Of course, you may elect to follow the **beta** release stream instead. Which ever stream you choose, this will put your firmware upgrades on *autopilot*, with the caveat that a `reboot` is required to actually apply the firmware in the file to the EEPROM.

Another option you may choose is to perform no firmware upgrades at all! There are two methods available to freeze your firmware revision temporarily or permanently:

- mask the `systemd` auto-update process:

```bash
sudo systemctl mask rpi-eeprom-update
```

- apply the `FREEZE_VERSION` parameter to the firmware configuration file; [see the documentation for details](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#updating-the-eeprom-configuration).

###### 3. Manual EEPROM firmware Upgrades & Retrogades:

For some, there may be occasions which demand a manual firmware upgrade. For example, a *new feature* is introduced, and you cannot wait for this feature to reach maturity and become part of the **critical/default** stream. Or, you may have applied a firmware upgrade, then concluded that it has created a problem and the firmware must be restored to a previous version.

The RPi organization's [GitHub repo contains a set of release notes for the bootloader EEPROM updates](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-eeprom/blob/master/firmware/release-notes.md). This can be very helpful wrt manual upgrade decisions.

In general, firmware upgrades AND firmware retrogrades are reliably performed using the `rpi-eeprom-update` script. As always, users should refer to the system manuals for detailed usage guidance; i.e. read `man rpi-eeprom-update` before undertaking any upgrades or retrogrades.

Pay particular attention to the OPTIONS in `man rpi-eeprom-update`. Two in particular are `-a` and `-f filename`:

- `-a` : automatically install the latest available update from the stream defined in `/etc/default/rpi-eeprom-update`. For example, if `FIRMWARE_RELEASE_STATUS="default"`, this command will install the latest file at `/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical`:

```bash
sudo rpi-eeprom-update -a
```

And as of today (Jan 29, 2023), on my system, that command would write the EEPROM with contents of the file at: `/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical/pieeprom-2022-12-07.bin`. The file at `/lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical/vl805-000138a1.bin` would also be applied, but only to the USB firmware area of the EEPROM. I've been unable to find any reliable documentation on this, but apparently the RPi organization has made hardware changes (to appear in Rev 1.4) that will obviate the need for separate updates for the USB.

- `-f filename` : install the named file; for example:

```bash
$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update -f /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical/pieeprom-2022-12-07.bin
```

This would update the EEPROM firmware, but exclude an upgrade to the USB firmware. It is equivalent to:

```bash
$ sudo rpi-eeprom-update -A vl805
```