# How can I change the RAM split?

Tags: debian, operating-systems, gpu

By default, the Pi is set to a 192MiB:64MiB RAM:VRAM split. As I will not be using the Pi for graphical purposes, I would like to change the split to allocate more normal RAM to ease swap usage.

Comment: There is a similar question and relevant answer [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/673/40).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are the RAM splits and what they should be used for.

- 240/16 - This is best if you are going to be doing nothing graphical, for example if you were using the Pi as a server and have no GUI.
- 224/32 - This is probably best if you are using the pi with a basic graphical desktop environment, without 3D.
- 192/64 - The default, probably the best general purpose one.
- 128/128 - Very high VRAM, Only really good if you are doing a very graphically intensive task.

---

There are several methods by which the RAM split can be managed:

### Manually

You can change the RAM split using this method:

```
sudo cp /boot/arm[ram-split]_start.elf /boot/start.elf
```

where `[ram-split]` is the amount of RAM to allocate to the CPU. After a reboot the new value will be applied.

### rpi-update

Hexxeh's [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) also supports changing the RAM split, you would run `rpi-update [ram-split]` where `[ram-split]` is the amount of RAM you want allocated to the CPU. After a reboot the split will be applied.

### Ram Selector Script

The best way is probably to use [this select4.sh script](http://sirlagz.net/?p=557), then selecting the appropriate RAM split. After you reboot the new split will be applied.

```
#!/bin/bash
##
## Raspberry Pi Memory Split Selector Script v4
## Author: SirLagz
## Website: http://sirlagz.net
##
## The purpose of this script is to make selecting the memory split
## on the RPi easy.
## Simply make this script executable if it's not already, move
## it to the directory with the elf files, and run it with ./select4.sh
## The menu should be pretty self explanatory.
##
cd /boot
clear
list=./*
b128det=0
b192det=0
b224det=0
b240det=0
bdefdet=0

for i in $list
do
    case $i in
        "./arm128_start.elf") b128det=1;;
        "./arm192_start.elf") b192det=1;;
        "./arm224_start.elf") b224det=1;;
        "./arm240_start.elf") b240det=1;;
        "./start.elf") bdefdet=1;;
    esac
done

if [[ "$b192det" == "$bdefdet" ]] ; then
    if cmp -s arm192_start.elf start.elf; then
        current=192
    fi
fi

if [[ "$b128det" == "$bdefdet" ]] ; then
    if cmp -s arm128_start.elf start.elf; then
        current=128
    fi
fi

if [[ "$b224det" == "$bdefdet" ]] ; then
    if cmp -s arm224_start.elf start.elf; then
        current=224
    fi
fi

if [[ "$b240det" == "$bdefdet" ]] ; then
    if cmp -s arm240_start.elf start.elf; then
        current=240
    fi
fi

declare -i vram
vram=256-$current
success=1
sysram=`awk '/MemTotal/ { printf("%.0f",$2/1024) }' /proc/meminfo`
echo "##################################"
echo "##      Raspberry Pi Memory     ##"
echo "##        Selector Script       ##"
echo "##################################"
echo "      Current Memory Split"
echo "        CPU $current/$vram VRAM"
echo "      Detected System RAM"
echo "          $sysram MB"
echo "##################################"
echo "1) Set CPU/VRAM split to 128/128"
echo "2) Set CPU/VRAM split to 192/64"
if [[ "$b240det" == 0 ]] ; then
echo "3) Set CPU/VRAM split to 240/16 (NOT DETECTED. DO NOT USE)"
else
echo "3) Set CPU/VRAM split to 240/16"
fi
if [[ "$b224det" == 1 ]] ; then
    echo "4) Set CPU/VRAM split to 224/32"
fi
echo "q) Quit"
echo "Enter Choice:";
read x
case $x in
1)
    rm start.elf && cp arm128_start.elf start.elf
    newram=128
;;
2)
    rm start.elf && cp arm192_start.elf start.elf
    newram=192
;;
3)
    if [[ "$b240det" == 1 ]] ; then
        rm start.elf && cp arm240_start.elf start.elf
        newram=240
    else
        echo "The arm240_start.elf was not detected. Not changing ram split."
        success=0
    fi
;;
4)
    rm start.elf && cp arm224_start.elf start.elf
    newram=224
;;
q|Q)
    exit 0
;;
*)
    $0
;;
esac

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo "Memory Split setting failed"
elif [[ $success == 1 ]]; then
    declare -i newvram
    newvram=256-$newram
    echo "Memory Split set to $newram/$newvram successfully"
fi

for i in $list
do
    case $i in
        "./arm128_start.elf") b128det=1;;
        "./arm192_start.elf") b192det=1;;
        "./arm224_start.elf") b224det=1;;
        "./arm240_start.elf") b240det=1;;
        "./start.elf") bdefdet=1;;
    esac
done

if [[ "$bdefdet" -ne 1 ]]; then
    $0
    echo "=============================================================================="
    echo "start.elf not detected. Please check that you have selected a valid ram split."
    echo "=============================================================================="
fi
```

Here's a [github link](https://raw.github.com/gist/3424582/bfb6548f0bf6b2e9368e88e0aef089083e0b634a/select4.sh) in case of link rot.

Comment: does it require a reboot afterwards?

Comment: @akavel Yes, as the start.elf is only executed upon startup. Editing now.

Comment: The four answers you posted have been merged. Although sometimes acceptable, I don't believe that having four separate answers addressing different aspects of the question added any value in this case. I hope no-one objects.

Answer (score 14):

## raspi-config

You can change the memory split using the `raspi-config` utility in either debian-wheezy or raspbian-wheezy.

Just run the utility: `sudo raspi-config` then select the memory split option (its about the 8th one in the list).

Answer (score 2):

## Checking your RAM split

Too big for a comment, but related. You can check your ram split by running this command

```
$ sha1sum /boot/*start.elf
a3f72ae7eae537800454de8e4cb231cbd176c0e1  /boot/arm128_start.elf
7784527719031c1c7fce6f72cf3a5c8c23565f24  /boot/arm192_start.elf
82c6be2c9098c0c9c3d71f45bf16c1dc5adfcf08  /boot/arm224_start.elf
82c6be2c9098c0c9c3d71f45bf16c1dc5adfcf08  /boot/start.elf
```

The split is given by the file that has the matching checksum, so in my case it's `224/32`

Comment: Although useful, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I wanted to check my current ram split because I didn't know what the default was and it wasn't called out in /boot/config.txt.  Unfortunately my system only had start.elf, so I tracked down the value through dmesg.  There's a line (on my system) that says "Memory: 448MB = 448MB total".  So I have a 448/64 split.