# pacman -Syu breaks Pi running Arch

Tags: boot, archlinux, packages

So I just booted up my raspberry pi running Linux Arch. I read several posts that instructed my to update the system using `pacman -Syu` so I did so and then attempted to reboot my pi.

However it wouldn't restart (the green light blinks once then nothing). I reimaged the SD card and it works fine again until I run `pacman -Syu`.

I also tried `pacman -Syu --ignore filesystem` and then forced filesystem, with the same result.

The output is what I'd expect, it updates around 50 packages, a few are saved as `.pacnew`s so I went and manually merged them according to the advice I found online, I tried several different possible ways on merging them as well, nothing seemed to work.

Does anyone have any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: That `s` should be a capital. What is the output from the update command?

Comment: @Jivings Sorry that was a typo editing

Comment: I would guess you are not merging the `.pacnew` files correctly. That could cause the system failures you describe.

Comment: @Jivings Do you know of somewhere where I can get some advice on how to merge them? I'm new to Arch

Comment: Come and join me in [chat] and I can try and help.

Comment: You don't need to restart after you update.

Comment: @JoshRagem you need to restart eventually

Comment: @Jivings you were right, I was messing up merging some stuff, thank god for vimdiff. Post that as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it

Comment: It would be interesting to plug a monitor and record the error messages displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, when packages with config files are upgraded, the files can change.
To deal with these files `pacman` appends them with the suffix `.pacnew`.

Merging of `.pacnew` files can be a tricky process. You can find more information about them on the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacnew_and_Pacsave_Files).

You can find your `pacnew` files with the following command:

```
find /etc -regextype posix-extended -regex ".+\.pacnew" 2> /dev/null
```

An easy way to merge the files is to use Yaourt if you have it. The following command will take you step by step through the process:

```
yaourt -C
```

Answer (score 2):

I am also using the Arch Linux ARM image from the raspberrypi.org and I did update the packages with the `pacman -Syu` command a couple of times, just did it now, without any problem.

Do you try to update the packages just after reimaging the SD card ?
Do you get an error message when running that command ?

You could try to skip the kernel and firmware packages by adding the following line in `/etc/pacman.conf` and see how it goes:

```
IgnorePkg   = linux-raspberrypi,linux-headers-raspberrypi,raspberrypi-firmware
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pi being what it is (brittle), and an upgrade changing many files, it is quite possible that you actually ran into a problem with the SD card. See [Filesystem corruption on the SD card](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2069/filesystem-corruption-on-the-sd-card/2113#2113) for an example.

May be trying with another card? Or trying to underclock the Pi?