# XMBC UI slow on RasPi. How to speed it up?

Tags: sd-card, kodi, gui

We can [run XBMC media player](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Raspberry_Pi) on Raspberry Pi - great!

While the playback is fine, the UI is somewhat slow. How do I speed it up?

For example, what is your experience with faster SD cards. is it worth it? Or, do you know some magic settings that will speed up the user interface?

Comment: This might be related to [GPU memory](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory). Have you tried adjusting `.elf` file under `/boot` directory?

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned you should probably adjust your memory split. The recommended memory split when running XBMC is 128MB. Run the line below and reboot:

**cp /boot/arm128_start.elf /boot/start.elf**