# Memory display on Raspberry Pi running raspbmc

Tags: raspbmc, memory

After lying around few months, finally I setup my Pi with raspbmc. But after starting up and when I went to see Systeminfo, it's showing 122MB max memory.

[image]

Did I receive model A, which is with a lower memory OR is there any issue with raspbmc ?

Comment: It should be noted that the plan is to ship the Model As with 256MB of memory. Having said this, I'm not convinced they will ship them at all now they are making such vast quantities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely have a model with 256mb if it has been laying around for a few months. The model B's with 512mb of memory have only been shipping for a week or so.

It is only showing the memory available to the CPU and not the total memory installed. Raspbmc runs a 50/50 memory split between the CPU and GPU.

ref: http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=378

Comment: On my order it says 256MB, I just rechecked order email. Model B with 512 is recent one. I want to confirm is it a raspmc thing or not, if Yes, how can I improve it to make use of 256MB memory.

Comment: @garikapati I am unclear what you mean are you saying that yes you have an early pi with 256mb or do you have a new pi with 512. Assuming a Pi with 256mb you are utilizing all of the Pi's memory you are devoting half of it to the CPU and the other half to the GPU. All of the Pi's run some memory split but Raspbmc uses the 50/50 split I mentioned in my answer. You may want to check this post http://www.raspbmc.com/2012/10/new-512mb-raspberry-pi-raspbmc/ and this forum thread http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=536

Comment: My bad in writing the Question...Yeah, it's never about 512MB one. Have to check the forums, 50/50 curious config. So if I run a regular Linux, it will shoe me 256MB ?

Comment: @garikapati no all of the Pi's no matter what OS they are running Occidentalis, Raspbian etc. Will display the memory dedicated to the CPU only. All of the Pi's run with some of the memory dedicated to the GPU and so for example under Raspbian I show 189104kb which corresponds to the 192/64 CPU/GPU split.

Comment: @garikapati: See [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/673/40) for more information about memory split.

Comment: As [Krzysztof Adamski](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1885/141) says: *128/128 - The most RAM GPU can get. Use it when you need a lot of memory for 3D graphic card and hardware accelerated video playback in high resolution. This split is needed for RaspBMC to work properly or to play fullHD video content with omxplayer without problems.*