# how to know if my Raspberrypi's Ram size is 265MB or 512MB

Tags: hardware, memory

I've just bought a new raspberry pi as a 512Mb Ram but [this website](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2012/10/19/read-the-manufacturing-code-to-identify-the-ram-your-pi-has-without-turning-it-on-piday-raspberrypi-raspberry_pi/) is saying that if my chip contains 2G so it is 265 Ram which is my case my chip number is

> k4p2g324ed-agc1

, so if you are sure how to identify your ram size from the code number I will be thankful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use chip number as described on the page you linked to. And from this, it seems that you have 2Gbit (256MB of memory).

The other way is to use `config.txt` file and set memory split for 512MB  to for example 128/384MB (gpu_mem_512=128) and then, after system startups, use `free -m` command to see how much total memory do you have. It should be about 384 MB in case of 512MB version of RaspberryPi. For more information about memory splits, refer to my answer to [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory/) question.