# Kivy -- Raspberry Pi not responding

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

I installed Raspbian on my RaspPi 3. Downloaded Jessie version of Kivy.

However, when I open 'showcase' or '3D monkey Demo' or 'Hello tutorial', the example shows but it *wont close out* .

The keyboard or mouse doesn't respond or interact with the application. I searched on other StackExchange q's but it only deals with RaspPi2 or lower problems.

How do I make my mouse and keyboard to interact with the application?

Help please…

Comment: Can you check the CPU utilization of your Pi. The reason being usually such issues get reported when the Pi stays in 100% utilization for a minute or 2. On my Raspberry Pi 2 the utulization shoots up to 100% if I open a browser and nothing more. Now I have stepped down from console by changing the runlevel. All the best. Happy coding !!.

Comment: Hello Varad, how do I check CPU utilization?

Like no key or mouse click works in the middle of an application.

Comment: Please look at the link http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4356/get-cpu-and-gpu-usage-on-raspberry-pi on how to get the cpu utilization. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Varad, but last question. 

I'm having difficulty understanding a bit w/ the link. May you post me the link  on how you changed the runlevel? 

Approx how much RAM you assigned to your GPU? This would be helpful so I could get the keyboard and mouse to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 ways

1. Refer the link http://www.modmypi.com/blog/boot-to-command-line-raspbian-jessie
2. You can go to sudo raspi-config and go the **Enable Boot to Desktop/Scratch** and select the option that boots to command line.

GPU can be set either through raspi-config or in config.txt file.

sudo raspi-config - > Advanced Options -> Memory Split and then set your value there.

gpu_mem_1024=512

I have set this value as 128 since I don't use GUI at all. The optimal value I suggest if use GUI is 512 otherwise it will be sluggish.

Also I had some issues with KeyBoard configurations which I resolved by selecting appropriate keyboard from

sudo raspi-config -> Advanced Options - > configure-keyboard

Hope this helps.