# Is there a way to check out the GPU usage (how busy it is) on a RPi3?

Tags: pi-3, gpu, measuring

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and would like to know how busy the GPU gets when I run certain tests to determine whether it would be possible for me to do certain things. I see that the GPU is a bit old (2014) as per:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=106901

What I'm after is something similar to what nVidia offers in their settings window showing a % of usage of the GPU. I don't expect a nice graphical tool, but a way to access that type of info somewhere would be fantastic!

[image]

OS Version

```
$ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

LSB info:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:  Raspbian
Description:     Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.3 (stretch)
Release:         9.3
Codename:        stretch
```

Comment: @Fabian, it looks like we don't have access to any info (as per that other thread) and that probably did not change sine 2013?

Comment: @Fabian Also I see that the other question was more about _"the split"_ (how much RAM is used by one and the other) rather than the CPU/GPU usage. Mine is clearly (I think) about the % usage of the GPU so I can get an idea of how much horse power I'm using and how much is still available for improvements to my software.

Comment: "you cannot currently get the GPU usage" https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4374/78211