# Raspbian wheezy with XBMC plays only audio for 1080p videos

Tags: kodi, 1080p

My current configuration:
 Raspberry pi, overclocked to second highest speed (Highest speed - Turbo isn't playing good, I get freezes, stutter in video etc)

```
 uname -a output:
 Linux raspberrypi 3.6.11+ #474 PREEMPT Thu Jun 13 17:14:42 BST 2013 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Installed XBMC using:
 http://michael.gorven.za.net/raspberrypi/xbmc

XBMC version (Frodo):

```
XBMC Media Center 12.2 Git:Unknown
Copyright (C) 2005-2012 Team XBMC - http://www.xbmc.org
```

I've required licenses, and I've used raspbmc successfully to play 1080p, however I was implementing https://github.com/gkaindl/ambi-tv so I need to get raspbian wheezy and then XBMC.

I'm starting XBMC with:

```
xbmc-standalone
```

The problem is when I play 1080p video only audio is streamed, however setup works perfectly for 720p and SD videos.
 I can't figure out what am I missing, I would appreciate any help in the matter.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to increase your video memory to at least 128 MB. For newer firmware version this can be done by adding the line

```
gpu_mem=128
```

(possible values: `16`, `64`, `128`, `256`) to your

```
/boot/config.txt
```

Helped for me.

Also see: [What is the optimum split of main versus GPU memory?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory)