# OpenElec on raspberry pi 2 B struggling to play 1080p

Tags: openelec, 1080p

I have recently bought, raspberry pi 2 Model B, with 1GB ram and quad core. Added 16GB samsung class 6 SD Card.

I have successfully installed OpenELEC on it with Aeon Nox MQ5 on it.

I have noticed Pi is little sluggish when you are moving between menu on home screen. It works but not very flawlessly. It stream videos from youtube without any problem in high quality. But when I am trying to play 1080p MKV files from Synology NAS it is struggling to play it.

**Has other people noticed same thing ?**

**Anyway to improve the performance.**

With different skin like Amber or Aeon Nox (standard) UI works fine but it still struggles to play 1080p MKV videos.

**Any suggestions ??**

Comment: do you face the same problems when playing the same file locally (or from a flash drive)? - if no, the problem is your network speed...!

Comment: It works fine locally ... if it is connected over the usb drive to Pi

Comment: well... then the RPi isn't the problem! - the transfer-speed is causing your problems... please check your cables, router/switch and/or server!

Comment: But I have another installation of Kodi on Macmini, and that playes same file perfectly fine over the network ... same network cable and removed from macmini to pi and playing same file, and pi is struggling ...

Comment: Have similar problems. Openelec 5.95.3.
I think the WiFi is not performing well.
I have much better results with an Intel Compute Stick with Windows and Kodi 15; but this is also a slightly more expensive solution.

Comment: @microchip78 how much is the video memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

- Increasing the memory dedicated for the GPU - on Raspbian etc this can be done via [`raspi-config`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/raspi-config.md), otherwise you need to edit the boot `config.txt` file (see [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory))
- Trying a different video format, by transcoding the video into something else, e.g. H264 (mp4) or Theora (ogv). This can be done via a tool like [FFMpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)
- Use a optimized player like [OMXplayer](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer) (this may be in used already)

Answer (score 0):

Check codec of your video. maybe you should buy codec license keys:
http://www.raspberrypi.com/license-keys/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the files in question are neither in mpeg2 nor vc1. anyway, the playback would be more like a slideshow, not "struggling" if it was software-decoded at this resolution.