# Screen gets black after raspberry pi has done the boot

Tags: boot, raspi-config

I have recently installed the lastest raspbian jessie version and it has worked fine. the raspberry has boot correctly and the graphics mode is OK. Then I have started to configure my wifi usb adapter and the raspberry pi camera. After a few reboots to check (first I have installed the wifi adapter and then the camera) where the raspberry has been launched correctly, the boot is not done. I mean, the raspberry is on, I have all the boot messages  in OK but the graphics mode does not appear. Instead the screen is black with the cursor pointing at the top left. It is impossible to set any command or to login with a user.

Do you know why this happen and how could I solve it (I imagine as last option I can install again the OS in the SD card)

I am using a SD 32 GB classe 10 and my raspberry is a B model.

Thanks,
Diego

Comment: I think to use the camera you do need to have a larger than normal proportion of the memory (512MB for your B?) allocated to the GPU.  When you say your RPi is a B can you clarify if that is a B rev 1.0/1.1/2.0 (the older models with a phono socket for composite video output) or a B+ or a 2 B (both of which have 4 USB sockets) but the 2 B has a main IC that can clearly be read to be a Broadcomm BCM238**6** (the other uses a BCM2385 but also has a memory chip fitted ON TOP of it so that the Broadcomm name and number is hidden).

Comment: Thanks for the information SlySven. I have a B rev. How I can add more memory space allocated to the GPU?

Comment: I have reinstalled again and it look like the problem start when I reboot after i have launch an update/upgrade and reboot. Is that possible?

Comment: Well, to answer your first: *using the search box in the top right of the page* (which people will find really useful if they try - honest!) [What is the optimum split of main versus gpu memory](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/673/what-is-the-optimum-split-of-main-versus-gpu-memory) seems to be the canonical answer - *though other answers **are** available*... 8-)

Comment: And your second: updating the system has probably *moved the goalposts* so that the new configuration/software combination needs more of either CPU or GPU than before the update...