# Raspberry Pi won't Boot Just shows Black Screen

Tags: openelec

I have had my raspberry pi running as a media centre using openelec. It has run fine for a few weeks and suddenly it has just stopped working and will not function. The PWR light shows RED, FDX and LNK show green and the 10M shows orange but the OK light isn't on.

Anyone know what I can do to fix/troubleshoot it?

Comment: Does it boot another card? Was SSH active? If so, does SSH come up? Have you got a Linux PC? If so, mount the SD card and study the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The elinux wiki has a page describing how to [troubleshoot your Pi](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting). It sounds like you may have a problem with the SD Card, firmware or one of the startup files (i.e., loader.bin, start.elf). Can you try booting using another card? You can find instructions for updating the firmware in the post [How do I update software and firmware?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/164/86).

Answer (score 1):

My 'black screen' problem was caused by an unneeded DVI --> Display Port cable. If your monitor has multiple cables as mine does, check that it is connected *only* to the π. If any cables are attached to an adaptor, remove it.