# e-CAM30_USB camera with raspberry pi

Tags: webcam

Can I use this USB camera with raspberry pi? When I use this with beagle board xm it does not require any driver.

[image]

Could you please give me a solution?

Comment: Hi,                                                       I am just started using raspberry pi. I don't know how I can enable this camera. I want to use this camera with OpenCV. Please tell me where I can start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not say which linux distribution (if any) you are using on your RPi. I suggest you to use Raspbian with all the latest kernel updates (check [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/164/how-do-i-update-software-and-firmware) how to update using the rpi-update tool), since latest updates improve USB host support (which is needed for your webcam to work).

Then I would advise you to log in your RPi by using SSH, not using any keyboard or screen, in order to have the minimum amount of connected devices. Ideally, I would experiment with just the webcam plugged in. More devices connected, more chances to experience problems with the USB stack of the RPi kernel.

Finally, plug your webcam in the RPi and check the output of `lsusb` command and also the log in `/var/log/kern.log` for useful informations.

You can find a little tutorial about using opencv on RPi [here](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/).