# Pi 3 Model B+ doesn't boot - Power Supply or broken?

Tags: pi-3, power, voltage, pi-3b+

I just bought a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. I also bought a power supply that the reseller sold specifically for the Pi - it delivers up to 3A.
However, the Pi doesn't boot. I gives me the rainbow screen with the yellow bolt - indicating low voltage. Also the red power led flashes randomly.
I measured the voltage at the GPIO pins, giving me 5.01V constantly.
But I also suspect that the Pis are being tested, before they are shipped.

Now I'm not sure whether the power supply simply produces voltage drops that are to short for my multimeter to detect or whether the Pi is simply broken.

Is there a way to test that?

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: How did you prepare the SD card?

Comment: Wrote an image to it. I also tried out an SD working fine in my old pi. So I can rule that out.

Comment: Was it the latest Raspbian image of 2018-03-13?  Older versions will not work.

Comment: Thank you, works now. How comes that older images produce that voltage issue?

Comment: It wasn't a voltage problem, you needed new boot files to boot the new hardware.  A simple way to get a consistent new system is to flash a new image (you might have been able to use apt update/upgrade/dist-upgrade as well but that doesn't always work).

Answer (score 1):

/boot/bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb is missing in older raspbian images. Just run

sudo rpi-update

on your booted previous raspberry pi to fetch the missing firmware. After that you can switch to your new raspberry pi 3b+ and boot it with your existing sd card.

Answer (score 0):

I tried 3 things. Only the last one fixed this problem for me:

1- copying bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb into  /boot/

2- sudo apt-get update / sudo apt-get upgrade / sudo rpi-update

3- complete re-install of the image from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/ (Version:March 2018 Release date:2018-03-13)