# pi-3b+ ubuntu-core boot problem

Tags: raspbian, ubuntu, pi-3b+

i've a pi-3b+ it boots raspbian but does not boot ubuntu-core. When i write ubuntu-core image for pi-3 stable from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/stable/current/ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz) the red led lights only. When i write ubuntu-core image for pi-3 edge from [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-core/16/edge/current/ubuntu-core-16-armhf+raspi3.img.xz) the red led lights 4 times long and 3 times short.
The power supply i use is 5.2V 1.35A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  [Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/) was released on 2018-03-14 and need [updated firmware](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81688/79866). It is very likely that the images from ubuntu you are using does not already have these firmware updates. `ubuntu-core-16-pi3.img.xz` is dated from 2018-01-10 22:19 and `ubuntu-core-16-armhf+raspi3.img.xz` is dated from 2018-01-03 08:40.