# Can't get past rainbow screen with Kali install process

Tags: sd-card, linux, noobs, kali, pi-3b+

I am new (to all of this, Pis, Linux, etc). This is my first real attempt at working directly with hardware as well.

I needed a new project so I got a Canakit started set which came with a Raspi 3B+, a 32gb samsung evo sd card, a power cable, heat sinks and screws and an hdmi cable and a case (which I am currently not using). I put on the heat sinks and used my Win 7 computer to burn the arm rp3 version of kali linux. I got the image directly from their site. I used win32diskimager.

It runs for awhile and then says it is complete. So I take it out and put it in the rp and plug it in. The power light is on, and the blinky light is blinking (what is that anyways, the activity light?). But All I get is the rainbow screen. I tired redownloading the disk image and actually installing win32 again to burn it for a second time. And I used a different adapter and port. Rainbow screen again. I even used a different outlet in case something was wrong with my surge protector. How do I make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting a rainbow screen and flashing red PWR LED with a new Raspberry Pi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81458/why-am-i-getting-a-rainbow-screen-and-flashing-red-pwr-led-with-a-new-raspberry)

Comment: Don't think so this time.  Latest version of Kali Linux is from January which pre-dates the B+.

Comment: *heat syncs* sound like really cool devices.

Comment: Try formatting the SD using SD Formatter then using Etcher to burn the image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Kali has been updated to work with the Raspberry Pi 3 B+ yet so I suggest downloading either Noobs or Raspbian directly and installing that at least temporarily until Kali is updated.  There's a lot more support for Raspbian anyway which is important when you are just starting out.

More importantly, welcome to Linux, Stack Exchange and the Raspberry PI - I hope you stick at it and have fun!

NOOBS: https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/

Comment: Isn't Kali just Debian with lots of tools? Raspbian with zenmap/nmap, wireshark and aircrack-ng would be more than enough to play with in the meantime and would confirm your kit works.