# Kali Linux image for Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: pi-3

I bought myself a new Raspberry Pi 3 B+ from year 2018. I try to install Kali Linux on it but on the installation page of Kali Linux it says the ARM image is for Raspberry Pi 2 and 3. Should the image also work on the Pi 3 B+?

I did everything for the installation on the SD card correctly but I get a rainbow screen and the Pi won't boot. There are no hardware faillures because I can succesfully load Raspbian software on it.

Any advice?

Comment: Very closely related: [Why am I getting a rainbow screen and flashing red PWR LED with a new Raspberry Pi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/81458/why-am-i-getting-a-rainbow-screen-and-flashing-red-pwr-led-with-a-new-raspberry)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kali Linux does not yet support the 3 B+.  Try Raspbian instead at least until Kali is updated.  Why do you want to use Kali?  The Raspbian respositories (Debian) also contains useful security packages that are included in Kali.

Comment: I wondered the exact same thing. In fact, I was under the impression that one would "install" raspberry pi under Kali - does the OP have it backwards?

Comment: I didn’t know that the same packages could be installed under raspbian. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 3):

You have to copy over the updated boot files to the boot partition on the MicroSD card.
You can get it from the raspberry pi's github repository 
[Here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware)

Code :

```
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware
```

`fdisk -l`

`mkdir /mnt/boot`

`mount /dev/disk2s1 /mnt/boot`

`cp -r firmware/boot/* /mnt/boot/`

`unmount /mnt/boot`

`rmdir /mnt/boot`

`rm -rf firmware`