# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ no wireless interfaces found

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, raspbian-jessie

I can connect to Wi-Fi when I use RPi 3B but when I boot the system with 3B+ it doesn't connect to Wi-Fi automatically and when I click on the top right to connect it to Wi-Fi, I see the error:

> no wireless interfaces found.

We tried

```
sudo rpi-update 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and some other common solutions on the internet but none of them solved the problem. I can connect to internet via Ethernet but I need to connect to Wi-Fi. I also tried to set the country code but it did not work.

Are there any other solutions we can try?

Comment: @joan Sorry about the confusion. I edited the question, hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: > "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

Comment: `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode. **THEN** you can start solving your problem.

Comment: See [How to set up networking/WiFi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) which describes the options for setup and common shortcomings.

Comment: @Milliways I ran rpi-update because the system did not boot on RPi 3B+. After the update I was able to boot the system so I don't know if removing the updates will solve my problem

Comment: @Canberk what you **SHOULD** have done was update/upgrade on the Pi3 **BEFORE** trying to boot the Pi3B+, but the listed commands should work. Your **ACTUAL** problem may be the old config files (which you have not listed).

Comment: @Milliways What I was trying to say was I ran these 3 commands on Pi 3 and after that I was able to boot the system on Pi3B+. Now my problem is I cannot connect to Wi-Fi on Pi3B+ even though I can connect on Pi3.

Comment: [Follow these instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md). If you encounter any problems, copy and paste the (relevant) contents of your terminal window here.

Answer (score 1):

I seems you take the SD Card from the *RPi 3B* and put it into the *RPi 3B+*. This cannot work because the *RPI 3B+* has new hardware, particular a new wifi chip. This needs new device drivers so it is recommended to use the [latest Raspbian images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/). If you want to update the SD Card from the *RPi 3B* you can do it as described in [Why am I getting a rainbow screen and flashing red PWR LED with a new Raspberry Pi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81688/79866)

Answer (score -1):

The problem was I was running Raspbian Jessie and it was not supported by Pi3B+. Installing the latest version of Raspbian Stretch solved my issue.

Comment: That's what I suggested in my answer. Please accept one answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.