# Can I modify an RPi2 image to boot on an RPi3 B+?

Tags: pi-2, boot-issues, kernel, ubuntu, pi-3b+

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+, and none of the operating systems that usually work on the RPi 3 will boot.  I've done a small bit of research, and I think this has something to do with an outdated bootloader (not quite sure)?

The Ubuntu Wiki has some information here:

[Booting the official Pi 2 image on the Pi 3B/3B+](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Booting_the_official_Pi_2_image_on_the_Pi_3B.2F3B.2B-)

It states that in order to boot on a Pi 3 B+, you need to update the boot files:

> For the Pi 3B+ you will also have to update the Pi bootloader files (bootcode.bin, fixup.dat and start.elf) on the system-boot partition.

With instructions on how to do so [here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Updating_the_Pi_GPU_firmware_and_bootloader_files)

I followed these instructions and, being the inexperienced person that I am, caused a kernel panic.

**Is there a way to modify *any* Pi 2 image to boot on the Pi 3 B+?**

Comment: "none of the operating systems that usually work on the RPi 3 will boot" is **UNTRUE** - the official Raspbian OS boots on **ALL** Pi. Users of other unsupported OS are assumed to be able to fix themselves. Ubuntu MATE has had **NO UPDATE** in over a year, although there should be a 18.04 image in September.

Comment: "I followed these instructions" - tell us what you did [exactly](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2197/33476). I doubt the instructions are wrong, perhaps you simply misunderstood them and without knowing what you did there's no way to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of the Raspbian image the SD Card was build. [Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/) was released on 2018-03-14 together with a Raspbian image **Raspbian Stretch 2018-03-13** that contains the support for RPi3B+. That version and all following are compatible to all Raspberry Pi Versions. All other images before run on all Raspberry Pi devices **except** RPi3B+.

So if your SD Card is build on a release before 2018-03-13 and was not upgraded it cannot run on a Raspberry Pi 3B+. Look at the [release notes](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/release_notes.txt) what images these are.

But there is a possibility to upgrade the old version to run on a RPi3B+. Look at [Why am I getting a rainbow screen and flashing red PWR LED with a new Raspberry Pi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81688/79866).

Comment: I want to run snappy Ubuntu core

Comment: @CurticeGough your question was: "*Is there a way to modify any Pi 2 image to boot on the Pi 3 B+?*" The answer is: yes it is. One of any image is the latest **Raspbian Stretch** image. You do not have to modify it.

Comment: sorry, I meant to ask if there was a way to modify every RPi 2 image.  Like a universal method that works with everything