# Raspberry Pi 3B+, installing Ubuntu Server (64bit)- problems

Tags: ubuntu, pi-3b+

**TL;DR: (Scroll down to bottom two questions)**

I have found dozens of "solutions" on the Raspberry Pi 3B which have worked for people and not with my 3B+.

I suspect that there is a very specific problem with the "+" version, due to Ubuntu's wiki (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi) stating:

> **Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (2018) functionality is not yet available with these images.**
>
> Raspberry Pi 3: ubuntu-18.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz (4G image, 296M compressed)
>      Updated 2018-04-28 (18.04 LTS)
>
> Raspberry Pi 3: ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz (4G image, 252M compressed)
>      Updated 2018-04-21 (16.04.4 LTS)

I have followed numerous guides on the 3B and a few guides specific to the 3B+ (not the 3B) and none of them have worked. I have flashed several "special 3B+" images onto my SD card and nothing works.

I have tried three different brands of cards, a total of 10 cards. I have tried four different USB power adapters ranging from 0.5A to 3.5A.

The furthest I have gotten is constant rainbow screen, although 90% of the time there was no HDMI signal (100% failure with the latest firmware from GitHub, which is **really** confusing to me).

As for the other indicators: Red light is constantly on (when powered). No other indicators on the Pi. When I did plug other devices in: Keyboard does not light up (even on powered USB splitter), LAN lights both dimly lit but DHCP never sees anything in that port.

I literally have setup two virtual machines to assist in my efforts, I have compiled all kinds of different projects including the u-boot for ARM in both 32 and 64-bit.

After spending two days (over 30 hours) working on this, I come with two questions:

## 1: Is it possible to get Ubuntu Server (64 bit) onto my Raspberry Pi 3B+?

## 2: If so, what are the specific steps?

I would really appreciate any help - I usually do not have problems like this.

Comment: And yes once I get it working, I will post the specific steps here - I will try to upload any hard-to-find files (e.g: uboot arm64) for anyone else to reuse as desired

Comment: `functionality is not yet available with these images` - perhaps eventually the good folks at Ubuntu will get things working with 3B+ - maybe in 18.10?

Answer (score 1):

Since the [release of Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-3-model-bplus-sale-now-35/) in March 2018 it seems that Ubuntu does not update it images with the new drivers the new hardware need. Look also at [Why am I getting a rainbow screen and flashing red PWR LED with a new Raspberry Pi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81688/79866). Obviously Ubuntu does have much interest to support Raspberry Pi. You should consider to change the operating system. I suggest to use Raspbian. It is also based on Debian like Ubuntu and it is the operating system official supported for the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: However they appear to have no intention of providing a 64-bit Debian. Only 32-bit.