# Kali linux won't boot on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, boot-issues, kali

I downloaded tge kali linux RaspberryPi 3 64 bit image from this site: https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/. The date of the image is 2019.1.

I burned the image on the sd card and it shows the rainbow image then it loads something but it never made it to the desktop. I don't use the SD reader on the pi because for some reason it doesn't boot kali but when I use the SD as a usb it "boots". I am stuck on a screen that it recognises usb ports, mouse and keyboard but doesn't show the desktop

Comment: Do you mean a 2014 RPi B+ or a 2018 RPi **3B+**?

Comment: @Dougie idk but it is brand new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok something weird happend it was saying: attached scsi removable disk
I unplugged the usb and added the sd on the sd rider directly without shutting down the RPi and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues installing Kali to the USB too. I didn't have an SD card and so I had to fix it without one. It was getting stuck at the rainbow screen because it couldn't find the boot files. I fixed the issue by modifying cmdline.txt to point to my USB device partitions. I also had to change /etc/fstab to point to my USB device partitions. I've written a detailed guide here:
[How to install Kali Linux on a USB for the RaspberryPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106762/how-to-install-kali-linux-on-a-usb-for-the-raspberrypi)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you have a brand new Pi b+ so it's very likely it is a Raspberry Pi 3B+. This need updated firmware and drivers and it is known that other distributions than Raspbian haven't supported it very quick. You can look about this issue  at [Why am I getting a rainbow screen and flashing red PWR LED with a new Raspberry Pi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81688/79866).

Please check if the kali linux image support the RPi 3B+. If the date of the image is less than 2018-03-14 it very likely that it doesn't support it.

Using first Raspbian and then putting kali linux back on will not help because the firmware/drivers are part of the image. Raspbian has two partitions. The first partition is the boot partition and is formated as **fat**. It contains the kernel, firmware and drivers to boot with. That is the part that must contain the updated firmware/drivers. The second partition is the root partition and formated as **ext4**. It contains the operating system. It may be possible that you also need updated kernel moduls from it.

Comment: It is a 3B+, so I should install raspbian again and update the drivers. Then put kali back on? I think is the latest image because I downloaded the image yesterday

Comment: @AndreasPaxih I have updated the answer with the last paragraph. The latest kali linux image must not necessarily have the date from yesterday before downloading it. Look what date the image file has on the download site. You don't tell us what image do you use, so I can't look for you.

Comment: The date is 2019.1, I downloaded tge kali linux RaspberryPi 3 64 bit the image from this site: https://www.offensive-security.com/kali-linux-arm-images/

Comment: @AndreasPaxih On that site you find: "*This page provides the links to download Kali Linux in its latest official release. For a release history, check our Kali Linux Releases page.*" Have you checked **Kali Linux Releases page**?

Comment: yes I have checked

Comment: @AndreasPaxih And do you find some entries about updates to Pi 3B+? You should because it's important update with firmware/driver.

Comment: I manage to solve the problem, but i don't know why it happened