# How to install Kali Linux on a USB for the RaspberryPi?

Tags: boot, pi-3b+, boot-issues, kali

Boot stuck at **"random: crng init done"** while using balenaEtcher or Win32 Disk Imager to flash Kali onto a USB.

Device: **Raspberry Pi 3B+** 
Image: **kali-linux-2019.4-rpi3-nexmon.img.xz** from offensive-security.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Easy Fix:

- Update `root` in cmdline.txt to `/dev/sda2` (the correct partition in your case) Eg: `root=/dev/sda2`
- Update `/etc/fstab` to update the partitions from `/dev/mmcblk0p1` and `/dev/mmcblk0p2` to your usb device partitions

### Full guide to what  worked for me to get Kali up and running from the USB drive:

- Make sure your pi board is USB bootable. Should work out of the box for 3B+ (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/msd.md)
- Download the official image for your pi model from offensive-security.com
- Use balenaEtcher or win32DiskImager to flash the image onto a USB Pendrive/HDD
- If you try booting now you will be stuck at "random: crng init done"
- To fix this, open the cmdline.txt on the Pendrive from a PC and change root to /dev/sda2 or whichever partition is relevant to your device. You can do some guesswork but sda2 should work in most cases: `root=/dev/sda2`
- You should now be able to boot but you will get stuck with some scripts. Press Ctrl + D when you are prompted. Enter the password which by default should be 'toor' and now you should have access to the terminal
- Next, you'll have to modify /etc/fstab. For this change directory to /etc and `vim fstab`

It should look something like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

And needs to be updated to something like this:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/sda1       /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
/dev/sda2       /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

*Note: we only change the path /dev/mmcblk0p1  to /dev/sda1 and likewise for the other depending on your device.*

- Reboot and you should be good to go.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.