# Kali boot from USB on Pi v4

Tags: usb, boot, kali

Has anyone been successful in booting the Raspberry Pi v4 from USB?

I have been successful in booting on a Pi v3 B+, using this as a guide: [How to install Kali Linux on a USB for the RaspberryPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106762/how-to-install-kali-linux-on-a-usb-for-the-raspberrypi)

However, I am unable to boot on a v4. I have performed the following;

- boot from latest Raspian on micro SD
- ran `rapsi-config` and updated the bootloader to latest (also tried factory)
- enabled USB boot if SD not available (also tried vice-versa)
- performed the steps outlined in [How to install Kali Linux on a USB for the RaspberryPi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106762/how-to-install-kali-linux-on-a-usb-for-the-raspberrypi)
- confirmed the Pi 4 will boot from USB via Raspian and Ubuntu using the same drive/ports

The Pi will never boot, instead it hangs on the start screen with the following errors:

```
Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 8GB
bootloader: c2f8c388 Apr 29 2021
update-ts: 1619712685

board: d03114 1fbc6018 dc:a6:32:fe:2a:5d
boot: mode USB-MSD 4 order f41 retry 1/128 restart 2/-1
SD: card not detected
part: 0 mbr [0x0c: 00000800 0x83:00040000 0x00:00000000 0x00:00000000]
fw: start4.elf fixup4.dat
net: down ip: 0.0.0.0 sn: 0.0.0.0 gw: 0.0.0.0
tftp: 0.0.0.0 00:00:00:00:00:00

Trying partition: 0
lba: 2048 oem: 'mkfs.fat' volume:' BOOT '
rsc 32 fat-sectors 2001 c-count 256062 c-size 1 r-dir 2 r-sec 0
Read config.txt bytes 2236 hnd 0x000220bl
HUB [01:00] 2.16 000000:01 init port 3 speed 1
Read start4.elf bytes 2252288 hnd 0x00017209
Read fixup4.dat bytes 5398 hnd 0x000002ec
Firmware: 3a8f1793b758d6fb7f375edaa260e069ecd34c88 Apr 27 2020 14:33:37
Ox00d03114 0x00000000 0x0000000f
start4.elf: is not compatible
USB-MSD boot requires newer software
Get the latest software from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/
01:20
```

I have also tried this other post I found here; https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?49970-RPI4-USB-Boot-for-Kali&highlight=raspberry+usb+boot

Any guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: the instructions in that kali post seems to be OK - the output above - is that what you get when you follow those instructions? seems like an issue with start4.elf if I read it correctly - of course, you could ask your question on the kali forum, they'd know more about kali than anyone

Answer (score 1):

Took me forever but what I ended up doing was mounting the filesystem in another linux os then changing the fstab to be correct this solved my issue now im booting on pi4 8gb with newest os on a usb hdd.

Comment: Could you add some example and more details?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a very quick and easy way: First go on your terminal and type 'sudo raspi-config'. Now go down to the advanced options section and hit enter. Now go on the A7 option and hit enter. Go to the E2 option, hit enter, hit enter on yes and ok. Now go down to the advanced options section again, go on Boot order, select USB Boot, enter ok and finish but don't reboot yet.
Lastly go on Imager and choose your OS as kali linux: Other specific purpose OS > Kali Linux > Raspberry pi 2,3,4 and 400 (32 bit). Now plug in your USB and go on choose storage using your USB. NOTE: ALL DATA WILL BE DELETED ON USB. Now click write and enter your password and you are done! After it has been written to your USB go on your terminal type 'sudo init 6' your pi should shut down, plug the USB in if you took it out, plug out the power cable and back in the pi and it should work!
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).