# RPi 3B + Undervoltage on Jessie but not on Stretch

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

My RPi is running flawlessly on Raspbian Stretch, but when i flash a Jessie it shows me a rainbow screen with undervoltage icon. I've tried a couple versions of Jessie, to no prevail.

I specificaly need Jessie for the project i'm making.

Comment: Jessie can't be used on a RPi3B+ Use Raspbian Buster.

Answer (score 3):

As already said by others, Raspbian Jessie cannot run on a RPi 3B+ because lack of support for the updated hardware design in particular for the WiFi chip. Further information you can find at [Why am I getting a rainbow screen and flashing red PWR LED with a new Raspberry Pi 3B+?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/81688/79866).

In addition, Raspbian Jessie is deprecated a long time and has definitely left support since 2020-01-01. It seems you better change your project to use an up to date Raspbian operating system.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run Jessie on a Pi3B+