# PiCamera with RPi v3 B+: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin CAMERA_LED not defined

Tags: raspicam

Sorry for the long-winded post. I understand this issue has been posted throughout various forums (including here), but even after following all of the advice I have seen, I am unable to get the Pi Camera (v2.1) to take any images or display video using Raspistill, the Python sample programs directly from *raspberrypi.org*, or programs that I have written on my Raspberry Pi v3 Model B+.

Before using trying the camera out, I made sure I was completely up to date via the following commands, and that the camera interface was enabled in RPi Configuration:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo rpi-update
sudo rpi-config
sudo reboot
```

If I try to use Raspistill, I get the following output:

```
sudo raspistill -v -o image.jpg

raspistill Camera App v1.3.11

Width 3280, Height 2464, quality 85, filename image.jpg
Time delay 5000, Raw no
Thumbnail enabled Yes, width 64, height 48, quality 35
Link to latest frame enabled  no
Full resolution preview No
Capture method : Single capture

Preview Yes, Full screen Yes
Preview window 0,0,1024,768
Opacity 255
Sharpness 0, Contrast 0, Brightness 50
Saturation 0, ISO 0, Video Stabilisation No, Exposure compensation 0
Exposure Mode 'auto', AWB Mode 'auto', Image Effect 'none'
Flicker Avoid Mode 'off'
Metering Mode 'average', Colour Effect Enabled No with U = 128, V = 128
Rotation 0, hflip No, vflip No
ROI x 0.000000, y 0.000000, w 1.000000 h 1.000000
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

If I try to run the following Python program:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
from time import sleep

camera = PiCamera()

camera.start_preview()
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/camera.py", line 4, in <module>
    camera = PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 433, in __init__
    self._init_preview()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 513, in _init_preview
    self, self._camera.outputs[self.CAMERA_PREVIEW_PORT])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/renderers.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.renderer.inputs[0].connect(source).enable()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 2212, in enable
    prefix="Failed to enable connection")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 184, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Failed to enable connection: Out of resources
```

However, it seems that the Raspberry Pi does detect the camera:

```
vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=1
```

Here are the things I've tried to fix this:

- I've set the GPU memory allocation to 256 MB (overkill probably, I know)
- Rebooted multiple times
- I'm aware that the SPI, I2C, and 1Wire interfaces can cause issues with the camera, so I've blacklisted the modules and changed the /etc/modules file (shown below)

**File - /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf:**

```
blacklist spi-bcm2708

blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

**File - /etc/modules:**

```
#w1-gpio pullup=1

#w1-therm

#i2c-bcm2708

#i2c-dev

#spi-bcm2708

snd-bcm2835

lirc_dev

lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=7
```

I'm not sure what to do from here. I have 20 GB free on my SD card, so I have enough available space.

---

**Edit July 1, 2018:**

Output of **free -l**:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:         766752      247836      275564       15596      243352      453304
Low:         766752      491188      275564
High:             0           0           0
Swap:        102396           0      102396
```

Output of **df**:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       30568540 8307800  20955356  29% /
devtmpfs          378768       0    378768   0% /dev
tmpfs             383376       0    383376   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             383376   10048    373328   3% /run
tmpfs               5120       4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs             383376       0    383376   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mmcblk0p1     43539   22419     21121  52% /boot
tmpfs              76672       0     76672   0% /run/user/1000
```

---

**Edit July 6, 2018:**

I tried with a fresh version of Raspbian and didn't use `rpi-update` when configuring, but nothing has changed. However, I did notice something interesting when looking at the GPU log:

Partial Output of **sudo vcdbg log msg**:

```
111335.842: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 134, power enable gpio = 133
111636.620: camsubs: Camera not found
111636.701: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 134, power enable gpio = 133
111937.465: camsubs: Camera not found
111937.542: camsubs: Looking for camera 0: i2c_port = 0, led gpio = 134, power enable gpio = 133
111939.220: camsubs: Camera found OK
111941.741: gpioman: gpioman_get_pin_num: pin CAMERA_LED not defined
```

Okay, that sheds some light on the problem. It seems to be getting caught up looking for a GPIO pin that isn't defined correctly. I don't know what documentation I could look at to find out more about this. `pinout` only shows the J8 header specification.

I've checked the SUNNY connector, that's seated properly. Could this be a firmware issue? I'm hoping it is not a hardware issue, neither of the components nor the ribbon cable seem to have any obvious damage.

I'm changing the title of the post to be more specific and in hopes that this will get more attention.

Comment: You have done to much updates. What does `rpi-config` is? You should not use `rpi-update` if you want a stable system [Do I still need rpi-update if I am using the latest version of Raspbian?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/64569/79866)

Comment: Edit in the output of `free` and `df`.

Comment: @Ingo I will try with a clean version of Raspbian and update without `rpi-config`, then update here.
@goldilocks I will do that as soon as I get home (around noon EST).

Comment: any luck with this error? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Manassa no luck - I ended up using a USB camera for this application.