# Raspbian problem after upgrade from stretch to buster

Tags: raspbian, apt, update, dpkg

I tried upgrading raspbian from Stretch to Buster using this tutorial:

> https://pimylifeup.com/upgrade-raspbian-stretch-to-raspbian-buster/

At the end of step 6 (maybe at 99% of the upgrade), I had a lot of errors.
Now, a couple of commands give me lots of warnings related to regular expressions. For example, when I dot `sudo apt update`, I get

```
W: Invalid regular expression '^linux-image-[a-z0-9]*$' in configuration option 'APT::NeverAutoRemove' will be ignored.
W: Invalid regular expression '^linux-image-[a-z0-9]*-[a-z0-9]*$' in configuration option 'APT::NeverAutoRemove' will be ignored.
```

I also get 2 dozens of theses kind of messages when opening `nano` and other commands :

```
Erreur dans /usr/share/nano/gentoo.nanorc à la ligne 18 : Mauvaise expr. rationnelle « \$[-0-9@*#?$!] » : Fin d'intervalle invalide
Erreur dans /usr/share/nano/gentoo.nanorc à la ligne 19 : Mauvaise expr. rationnelle « \$\{[#!]?([-@*#?$!]|[0-9]+|[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*)(\[([[:digit:]]|@)+\])?(([#%/]|:?[-=?+])[^}]*\}|\[|\}) » : Fin d'intervalle invalide
```

For those not speaking french, it says something about "bad regular expressions".

I also had a lot of errors about `dpkg`. When doing `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, 4 packages seemed to cause problem :

```
gnome-icon-theme
exim4-config
exim4-base
exim4-daemon-light
```

I did a `sudo apt remove --purge` of these four packages. It solved the errors about dpkg, but I still have the errors about regular expressions.

Comment: If you choose to ignore the Foundation advice and try an unsupported upgrade you have to debug the inevitable issues. Most of us did a fresh install (which is faster in the long run).

Comment: In your case the [last point](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2198/33476) of the discussion about the merits of tutorials fully applies. You shouldn't have run [`sudo rpi-update`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4363/33476): this installs *test* versions of kernel and firmware. If anything, that makes the upgrade harder to complete.

Comment: So you think the problem is due to the `rpi-update` command ? Is there a way to downgrade to the last supported firmware version ?

Comment: Please prepend the commands with `LANG=C` before posting them. E.g. `LANG=C ls no-file` should give you `ls: cannot access 'no-file': No such file or directory`.

Comment: It works ! When I add LANG=C before my commands, there's no more regex errors. What does it means ? How to make this fix permanent ?